# How to print out the one keyword that was matched by method any(keyword in string)?

Tags: python, list

Simple question: how do I print out the exact keyword that was found and made any() turn True? Using `s` returns index number or 0, whereas I'd need the exact keyword that triggered it.

```
if any(s in source for s in keywords):
    print(...)
```

source is a long string(source code)

keywords is a list

Comment: You would need to check each truth value individually instead of using `any()`.

Comment: Use a `for` loop. When the condition is true, print the keyword and break out of the loop.

Comment: Just use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to iterate over this manually and break the loop on the first match

```py
keywords = ["foo", "BaR", "baz"]
source = "there was a fight yesterday. police reported that a fight broken out in a local bar but no one was injured. police have arrested a man named baz"

for k in keywords:
    if k.lower() in source.lower():
        print(k)
        break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
BaR
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand but I probably don't. I forgot to add in the OP that source is a long string (source code) and keywords is a list obviously. Does that change anything? Also - if there were more source codes in a list, does this solution with break keep iterating over the same string then, the next one, or?

Comment: So you could split the string into words if you seperate by space (i will update the example. The loop will stop as soon as one match is made, it wont keep looking after the first match

Comment: thanks, how to make it work without separating by space? in source codes people can try to obstruct the keywords I’m looking for or I’m looking starting from the middle of a common phrase thinking they might have user upper/lowercase as the first letter or preceed it by some symbol

Comment: ah i see what you mean, refactored the example so it now looks for keywords in source regardless of case